# Counting Pairs Recursively

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.6

Write a recursive function called countpairs that has a parameter, ‘s’, a string. The function will
count the number of pairs of repeated characters in a string.
Pairs of characters cannot overlap e.g. ‘aaa’ counts as one pair of ‘a’s followed by a single ‘a’.
Call the module that contains your function ‘pairs_mod.py’.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Show some of your work and you might be able to get some help.

Comment: Your code should probably look at the first two characters of a string, then call itself on some substring of that string.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's been over a week, I'm going to assume that this homework came due already and it's safe to provide a complete answer.  Let's do it without ugly numeric indexes by using Python 3 unpacking:

```
def countpairs(string):
    if string:
        first, *second_on = string

        if second_on:
            second, *third_on = second_on

            if first == second:
                return 1 + countpairs(third_on)

            return countpairs(second_on)  # outdent a level and still works!  Work out why.

    return 0

for word in ['', 'I', 'oo', 'aaa', 'zzzz', 'bookkeeper']:
    print(word, ":", countpairs(word))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
 : 0
I : 0
oo : 1
aaa : 1
zzzz : 2
bookkeeper : 3
>
```